# Why is there a space in between the ul and first li element?

Tags: html, css

The space is not between the inline block elements. it's happening before the first li and after the last li. The padding does not add up to 100% because of this. I have tried removing the white space and it doesnt sem to be helping because its not showing space between the inline elements.

HTML:

```css
    header {
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
     margin: 0;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    #page {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    #backgroundimg {
     display: none;
     opacity: 0.4;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    #navpane {
     text-align: center;
     height: 60px;
     width: 100%;
     background: #d7dfed;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.4;
     top: 0;
    }
    
    #options {
     list-style: none;
     max-width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 10%;
     
    }
    
    #options li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0 10%;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: none;
    }
    
    #options a {
     float: left;
     font-size: 30px;
     padding: 15px 0px;
    }
     
    #shirtdrop {
     background-color: inherit;
     outline: none;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    #shoedrop {
     max-width: 140px;
     background-color: inherit;
     outline: none;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    #pantsdrop {
     background-color: inherit;
     outline: none;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
    }
     
    #photochanger {
     position: absolute;
     height: 20%;
     width: 70%;
     border: black;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-style: solid;
     bottom: 45%;
     left: 15%;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html id="page">
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <img id="backgroundimg" onload="fadeIn(backgroundimg)" src="C:\Users\Jessica and Larry\Desktop\Projects\Test Template 1\img\background1.jpg">
      <div id="navpane">
       <ul id="options"><li><button id="shirtdrop"><a>Shirts</a></button></li><li><button id="shoedrop"><a>Pants</a></button></li><li><button id="pantsdrop"><a>Shoes</a></button></li></ul>
      </div>
      <div id="photochanger">
        <img>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you be more precise about the *space* ... you have a lot of spaces

Answer (score 0):

**There's a couple reasons for your mysteriously additional space:**

1. You are using an unordered list item (`ul`) which gets a small padding by default from most browsers.
2. You are adding your own padding to your `ul` and `li` elements.

**Solution**

Remove your paddings on your `li` and `ul` styles and use **flexbox**. Simply apply a `display: flex;` on the parent element, then flex (`flex: 1`) each child element. Now they should always fit perfectly into the the parent container, no matter how big or small your screen resizes. Using flexbox also means you no longer have to go through the pain of adding up your percentages to ensure that you use 100%.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#backgroundimg {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navpane {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d7dfed;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.4;
  top: 0;
}

#options {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex; //add this
  //padding: 0 10%; ---> remove this
}

.option {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1; // add this
  //padding: 0 10%; ---> remove this
  margin: 0;
  text-align: none;
}

#options a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}

#shirtdrop {
  background-color: inherit;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#shoedrop {
  max-width: 140px;
  background-color: inherit;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#pantsdrop {
  background-color: inherit;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#photochanger {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 70%;
  border: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html id="page">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="backgroundimg" onload="fadeIn(backgroundimg)" src="C:\Users\Jessica and Larry\Desktop\Projects\Test Template 1\img\background1.jpg">
  <div id="navpane">
    <div id="options">
      <div class="option"><button id="shirtdrop"><a>Shirts</a></button></div>
      <div class="option"><button id="shoedrop"><a>Pants</a></button></div>
      <div class="option"><button id="pantsdrop"><a>Shoes</a></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="photochanger">
    <img>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```